# Swift syntax: index of array element accessed in setter?

Tags: arrays, swift, setter, subscript

Say I have an array of Strings with a didSet:

```
var bar: [String] = [] {
    didSet {
        println("Set to \(bar)")
    }
}
```

Setting some elements gives us:

```
bar = ["Hello", "world"] // Set to [Hello, world]
bar[0] = "Howdy" // Set to [Howdy, world]
```

**Question**: in my didSet, how do I get the *index* of the element which was set?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have direct access to the index of the changed element, in part because setting a new value at a particular index is only one action that will trigger the `didSet` handler. Any mutating method will result in a call:

```
bar = ["Hello", "world"]                       // Set to [Hello, world]
bar[0] = "Howdy"                               // Set to [Howdy, world]
bar.insert("cruel", atIndex: 1)                // Set to [Howdy, cruel, world]
bar.replaceRange(0..<1, with: ["So", "long"])  // Set to [So, long, cruel, world]
bar.removeRange(2..<3)                         // Set to [So, long, world]
bar.append("!")                                // Set to [So, long, world, !]
bar.removeAll()                                // Set to []
```

Inside the `didSet` handler, you do have access to a special variable named `oldValue`, which contains the previous value of the observed variable. If you need more than that you'd need to implement a `struct` or `class` that uses an `Array` for storage but provides its own true accessor methods.

Comment: Ok... that makes sense.  So, maybe the question is actually:  if you were to override the subscript() method for the array, what would that look like?  I'm lost on the syntax at that point...

Comment: The problem there is that `Array` is a struct, so you can't subclass and override the subscript. (This is the part where Objective-C stalwarts begin to gnash their teeth.) You'd need to create a whole *new* type, with an `Array` as a property and the logic you want in its subscript and get/set methods.

Comment: What's your use case? Is this an array you'll be creating and working with completely, or are you trying to monitor the changes in an array from somewhere else?

Comment: It's the later -- the array is a property, and I want to know when it changes. (Yes, there are other ways to implement that functionality, but I wanted to know if there was some clever way of doing it in this spiffy new language!). I wonder if it's possible to implement this an extension to ```Array```?